# How come the largest value that can be stored in a bit is 127?

Tags: memory, size, byte, storage, bit

The decimal number 128, is 10000000 in binary. Isn't this 8 bits? How come byte's highest value is 127 then? Thankyou!!

Comment: Byte value is 0-255 unsigned, or -127 to +127 signed.

Answer (score 0):

Counting is zero based - it starts at 0.
Hence 0 to 127 is 128 items and the maximum value is 127.

Note that this assumes that you are talking about signed 8 bit bytes/integers.

For unsigned 8 bit bytes/integers the maximum value that can be represented is 255 (0-255 is 256 items).

Answer (score 0):

In two's complement representation, you have to allow for *negative* numbers as well.

Eight bits will give you 256 distinct values, -128 thru 127 inclusive.

```
00000000 - 01111111     0 to 127
10000000 - 11111111  -128 to  -1 (or 128 to 255 for unsigned).
```

Note that there are *other* encoding schemes, such as ones' complement or sign/magnitude, which have slightly different properties. Both those have a positive *and* negative zero so the range is `-127..127`.